# how to compare two infinitely large numbers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating an algorithm where a metric may take 3 values:

- Infinite
- Too large but not infinite
- Some number that is the result of a calculation

Now, `math.inf` handles the infinite.

The result of the third value has no determined borders. But, I want the second value to be always smaller than infinite and always larger than the third value. Therefore I cannot give it some very large number like `999999999999999` since there is always a possibility that the calculation may exceed it.

What I am looking for is another constant like `Ellipsis` of Python 2.

How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try `sys.float_info.max`:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.float_info.max
1.7976931348623157e+308
```

According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.float_info), it's the "maximum representable positive *finite* float".